# Follow Up script in PHP MYSQL with auto updating

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am trying to develop a PHP script to follow up my clients. All follow up details and next follow up details will be saved in a mysql table. Is there any way that i can get an automatic email to remind me the follow up details on the date when it is scheduled.

Can it be done via cron job? or any other script? Please suggest me

Comment: It can be done with a cron job :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using cronjob. If your working in localhost create task . Task which act as cronjob in localhost .

Comment: with the cron job i am getting details everyday or i can set the schedule, but i want an auto-responder that send the mail whenever it matched with entered date in database

Comment: first select entered date from database . If it is matched write code for mail auto-responder ..